# Modify css file (minify) using HttpModule: GZip CRC check fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, gzip, httpmodule, crc

i am using the following code to minify my css on the fly:

```
namespace MyCMS.Modules
{
    public class CSSModule : IHttpModule
    {
        void IHttpModule.Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
        }

        void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpContext context = app.Context;

            if (app.Request.RawUrl.Contains(".css"))
            {
                context.Response.Filter = new CSSFilter(app.Response.Filter);
            }
        }

        private class CSSFilter : Stream
        {
            public CSSFilter(Stream sink) { _sink = sink; }
            private Stream _sink;

            public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
            public override bool CanSeek { get { return true; } }
            public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }
            public override void Flush() { _sink.Flush(); }
            public override long Length { get { return 0; } }
            private long _position;
            public override long Position
            {
                get { return _position; }
                set { _position = value; }
            }

            public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { return _sink.Read(buffer, offset, count); }
            public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) { return _sink.Seek(offset, origin); }
            public override void SetLength(long value) { _sink.SetLength(value); }
            public override void Close() { _sink.Close(); }
            public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[count];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, data, 0, count);
                string html = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);

                html = Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.CssCompressor.Compress(html,0, Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.CssCompressionType.Hybrid, true);

                byte[] outdata = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html);
                _sink.Write(outdata, 0, outdata.GetLength(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the CRC of the GZip ( which is enabled on the server ) fails.
I do understand why it fails, since the file content was `X` and now its `Y` (minified),
and the original CRC was calculated for `X`, not `Y`.

what can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample MVC Application with CSSModule ,

With out module Site.css size was ~6kb.

Using module Site.css size ~1kb.

May be it will help you.

Link: http://www.mediafire.com/?a86fqg1zqy44ssc

http://www.sendspace.com/file/exxrj5

Comment: i do not use webresource.axd, and would not consider of using it, i gave the css module as an example, but i need to rewrite the filter output in some files, that is why i posted the question.